# -bash: ./setantenv.sh: Permission denied

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to install hybris software on my mac os system and my system have the prerequisites like 64 bit os, 4 mb…ram…..etc. To run `ant` command I need to set up a ant environment first. There is a file called `setantenv.sh` file in my platform folder. In mac terminal I am in platform folder and typing `./setantenv` and pressing enter. I am getting the following error. I tried different commands like `chmod +x setantenv.sh` or `chmod 755 platform`, BUT I could not succeed. After the successful environment setup only I can run my `ant clean all` command

```
-bash: ./setantenv.sh: Permission denied
```

Please help me with each steps to solve this issue. thanks

Comment: chmod a+x setantenv.sh

Comment: DrDSAugustines-MacBook-Air:platform DrDSA$ sh setantenv.sh
Setting ant home to: /Users/DrDSA/hybrissw/bin/platform/apache-ant-1.9.1
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.1 compiled on May 15 2013

Comment: DrDSAugustines-MacBook-Air:platform DrDSA$ ant clean all
Buildfile: /Users/DrDSA/hybrissw/bin/platform/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/Users/DrDSA/hybrissw/bin/platform/build.xml:20: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/DrDSA/hybrissw/bin/platform/resources/ant/antmacros.xml:69: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/DrDSA/hybrissw/bin/platform/resources/ant/util.xml:201: **** WRONG ANT VERSION **** 

 Environment check failed: You are using a not supported version of Ant. 
 Please make sure you are using Ant 1.9.1.

Comment: ou are currently using: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on June 3 2011.
 
 TIP: Use the ant version shipped with hybris Platform by simply
 executing the "setantenv.bat" (windows) or ". ./setantenv.sh" (unix) 
 batch file in the platform directory. After this the correct version 
 is used and you can call ant again.
 
 If you are using eclipse you can configure a different ANT_HOME under
 Windows->Preferences->Ant->Runtime->Ant Home... Button.

Comment: I am not able to succeed so pls help me

Comment: the message is self explanatory you're using the wrong ant version.  install the latest version of ant, set ANT_HOME to the instalation folder of that new version and retry the setantenv.sh

Comment: DrDSAugustines-MacBook-Air:platform DrDSA$ sh setantenv.sh
Setting ant home to: /Users/DrDSA/hybrissw/bin/platform/apache-ant-1.9.1
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.1 compiled on May 15 2013
DrDSAugustines-MacBook-Air:platform DrDSA$ ant clean all
Buildfile: /Users/DrDSA/hybrissw/bin/platform/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/Users/DrDSA/hybrissw/bin/platform/build.xml:20: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/DrDSA/hybrissw/bin/platform/resources/ant/antmacros.xml:69: The following error occurred while executing this line:

Comment: /Users/DrDSA/hybrissw/bin/platform/resources/ant/util.xml:201: **** WRONG ANT VERSION **** 

 Environment check failed: You are using a not supported version of Ant. 
 Please make sure you are using Ant 1.9.1.

 You are currently using: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on June 3 2011.
 
 TIP: Use the ant version shipped with hybris Platform by simply
 executing the "setantenv.bat" (windows) or ". ./setantenv.sh" (unix) 
 batch file in the platform directory. After this the correct version 
 is used and you can call ant again.

Comment: ". ./setantenv.sh" (unix) batch file in the platform directory. After this the correct version is used and you can call ant again.

Answer (score 8):

First off, you might just be able to fix it by setting the executable bit:

```
chmod a+x setantenv.sh
```

But I am also not sure if you are doing the correct call. You need to *source* the setantenv.sh file, so you need to do:

```
. ./setantenv.sh
```

(the leading "." is the source command and then you point to the file that you are sourcing) 
So effectively, the `setantenv.sh` file doesn't really need the executable bit.

The errors you get happen because you have an older version of ant in your current system, the `setantenv.sh` will point your terminal to the correct one (that is shipped with each hybris version and resides in $HYBRIS_HOME/bin/platform)
So once you do it right, that error should disappear.
Note that you need to do this `. ./setantenv.sh` every time you open a new terminal.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Whats sad about this is while hybris is a different animal, all the well-intentioned answers here are invalid when it comes to hybris; you might want to headline your answer by saying something like 'attn: this is hybris-specific, other answers for linux will not work !'

Comment: `chmod -x setantenv.sh` - this will remove executable bit, exact opposite of what you want

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 steps to getting this to work.
Navigate to hybris/bin/platform

1) Execute the command 'chmod 777 setantenv.sh'
2) In the terminal, type 'bash' and press enter. This will take you to bash prompt.
3) Type '. ./setantenv.sh'.

These 3 steps will work.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I fix it by removing the if condition at the beginning.
Replace your setantenv.sh with below bash code.

```
PLATFORM_HOME=`pwd`
export PLATFORM_HOME
export ANT_OPTS="-Xmx512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
export ANT_HOME=$PLATFORM_HOME/apache-ant-1.9.1
chmod +x "$ANT_HOME/bin/ant"
chmod +x "$PLATFORM_HOME/license.sh"
export PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

$ > chmod a+x setantenv.sh

$ > . ./setantenv.sh